# Alternative to Net::SFTP

Tags: perl, ftp, sftp

I want to switch a file upload from FTP to SFTP. But I cannot install [Net::SFTP](http://search.cpan.org/~dbrobins/Net-SFTP-0.10/lib/Net/SFTP.pm) because our system administrator does not like it (read: **NO!**). It is old, seems unmaintained and ratings on CPAN [say it is buggy](http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/Net-SFTP). Are there any alternatives available? Or am I overly paranoid and it actually works quite well?

**Edit:** I should have mentioned that I need one that can handle password authentication without user input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's only matter of bugs in `Net::SFTP`, you can try alternatives like [`Net::SFTP::Foreign`](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aSFTP%3a%3aForeign)
 or [`Net::SSH2`](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aSSH2). See [*Net::SFTP::Foreign Vs. Net::SFTP Vs. Net::SSH2::SFTP*](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aSFTP%3a%3aForeign#Net%3a%3aSFTP%3a%3aForeign-Vs.-Net%3a%3aSFTP-Vs.-Net%3a%3aSSH2%3a%3aSFTP) for a brief comparison.

Comment: I hadn't looked `Net::SFTP::Foreign`. I've seen it in the lib-dir, though. I will look at it, thank you!

Comment: It took me some time to get all the dependencies for `Net::SFTP::Foreign`. There still are some issues as all the servers I have tried so far do not like the `-s sftp` subsystem it puts on the `ssh` command line. I will need to figure that out, but I still believe this is theway to go. Thank you for pointing me there.

Comment: @simbabque: For those servers that do not like the `-s sftp` thing, call Net::SFTP::Foreign constructor with `ssh1 => 1`

Comment: @salva: we tried that, it didn't work. It says `#23759 1341227061.00000 _conn_lost: _conn_lost #23759 1341227061.00000 _set_status: _set_status code: 6, str: No connection` and 'Connection to remote server stalled'

Comment: @simbabque: are you able to connect to those servers using any other SFTP client (i.e. OpenSSH sftp or PuTTY psftp)? is there any particularity about them?

Comment: I am able to do it with Linux `sftp` from the command line. I'm also able to use a FileZilla on Windows. I tried a local machine as well as the remote one, but for that I still need to get hold of a remote administrator.

Answer (score 1):

expect, Net::SCP, or Net::SCP::Expect. i haven't used the modules, so i can't vouch for them, but it can't hurt to try them out. you should be able to install modules in your home dir with PREFIX via Makefile.pl or cpan shell and then experiment away.

```
perl Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=/home/<you>/lib

o conf makepl_arg INSTALL_BASE=/home/<you>/lib
```